# How does each backup/nodes get 2f replies in PBFT?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, fault-tolerance

In Practical Byzantine Fault Tolerance(PBFT), the reason why `3f+1` is needed as the way I understand is to allow for the worst case scenario where:

```
1. f+1 nodes are normal
2. f nodes are unresponsive
3. f nodes are faulty
```

So in the `PREPARE` phase, how is it possible for each node to receive `2f` similar `PREPARE` messages from other nodes to start the `COMMIT` phase?

Since only `f+1` nodes can reliably send the same `PREPARE` message, each node should only receive `f` of the same `PREPARE` message (not counting their own). So how is it possible for them to receive `2f` `PREPARE` message to start the quorum and proceed to the next stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following assertion is incorrect

```
1. f+1 nodes are normal
2. f nodes are unresponsive
3. f nodes are faulty
```

**3f+1** means that PBFT tolerates up to **f** faulty nodes only, where faulty means unavailable, unresponsive or malicious.

PBFT is focused on satisfying **safety** (results are valid and identical at all nodes) and **liveness** (nodes that don’t fail always produce a result) properties.

To achieve **liveness**, there must be a non-failed quorum (Q) available. So given N nodes and f faulty nodes, you end up with

**Q <= N-f**

For **safety**, the intersection of two quorums must contain at least one non-faulty node.  So given N nodes and quorum size Q, the following must be true for two intersecting quorums:

2Q - N > f => N + f < 2Q (because all f nodes can be malicious)
Recall for liveness Q <= N-f, so

2(N-f) - N > f => N > 3f

Assume N = 3f + 1 and again for liveness N + f < 2Q =>
(3f + 1) + f < 2Q which means that the minimum quorum size for safety in the byzantine case is now 2f+1.  And since a quorum must be available in the presence of f faulty nodes (2f+1+f), you get 3f+1.

There are more formal ways to demonstrate the proof, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: If so, how did they arrive at 3f+1 minimum req?

Comment: Because from the paper, it seems like there are two separate groups